# How to filter out "bad-len 0" packets with tcpdump?

Tags: freebsd, network-monitoring, tcpdump

When I listen internal network interface of router on freebsd, I get outputs like this

```
10:36:02.372026 IP 192.168.1.11.8888 > 192.168.1.2.49831: Flags [.], ack 1097, win 65050, length 0
10:36:02.374275 IP 46.163.78.160.123 > 192.168.1.2.32999: NTPv4, Server, length 48
10:36:02.376121 IP bad-len 0
```

My purpose is that filter out to "bad-len 0" packets with tcpdump itself (not grep etc.)
I tried to write "greater 0" filter options but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this expression to filter ip packets with zero in ip length header feild:

```
tcpdump -petnvv -i em0 'ip[2:2] = 0'
```

See pcap-filter(4) for tcpdump expression syntax and RFC 791 or other resources, [e. g. this](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/ip.htm) for ip header structure.